# Reading animated JPEG ("MVIMG_") in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, jpeg

My Android phone is capable of taking some kind of "animated" JPEG pictures, quite bcause I couldn't use that feature the proper way.

Now that I have cable-transferred my pictures to my desktop to save on space, how can I see them animated?

They are named "MVIMG" and timestamped. If I open them with stock Google Photo application, they will animate into a loop.

Is there any equivalent in Windows? I have tries Microsoft's stock Photos app, but they are still. On my phone, they move

Answer (score 4):

So apparently this is a custom file format consisting of a JPEG image and a MP4 video.

I found [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/keith-turner/motion-photos) containing a Bash script to extract the video part of the file.

Because the (Apache-2.0-licensed) script is quite short and easy to understand, I’ll quote it here:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> function extract {
>   local file=$1
>
>   local newFile=${file/[.]jpg/.mp4}
>
>   if [[ -f "$newFile" ]]; then
>     echo "File $newFile exists, so ignoring $file"
>   else
>     # find the offset of the string 'ftypmp42' in the file
>     local lines=( $(grep --only-matching --byte-offset --binary --text ftypmp42  $file| cut -f 1 -d:) )
>
>     # check that it was only found once in the file.. if not, well script probably needs improvement
>     if (( ${#lines[@]} == 1 )) ; then
>       # the mp4 begins 3 byte before the string 'ftypmp42'
>       local offset=$(( ${lines[0]} - 3))
>
>       # extract everything beginning at offset to another file
>       tail -c +$offset $file > $newFile
>     else
>       echo "Not processing $file because the string 'ftypmp42' did not occur exactly once in file"
>     fi
>   fi
> }
>
> for f in "$@"; do
>   if [[ "$f" == MVIMG*jpg ]]; then
>     extract $f
>   else
>     echo "Ignoring $f because its file name does not match MVIMG*jpg pattern"
>   fi
> done
> ```

To run it, you need `bash`, `grep` and `tail`, all of which are available on almost any Linux distribution. Since you’re using Windows 10, you could use WSL and [Debian](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MSVKQC78PK6).